# What does "except that a default constructed array is not empty" mean?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdarray

In N3337, I'm reading §23.3.2.1/3 it states:

> An `array` satisfies all of the requirements of a container and of a
>   reversible container (23.2), except that a default constructed `array`
>   object is not empty and that swap does not have constant complexity.

In §23.2.1, Table 96 Container Requirements, it shows a default constructed object `X u;` where the post condition is `u.empty()`. Presumably then, the following:

```
std::array<int, 0> a;
```

should result with `a.empty()` outputting `1`, which it does. So what does "empty" mean here?

Comment: And what about `std::array<int, 5> a;`?

Comment: `a.empty()` is true in this case because `N == 0`, not because it was default constructed. And the phrase "except that ... not empty" is clearly just making an exception to the requirement, meaning that a default constructed array is not required to be empty (because its emptiness depends only on the value of its constant size N). I agree that it is poorly phrased, nobody's perfect, and writing standard linguo is hard, give those guys a break and stop nitpicking passages, especially ones where the real meaning is so obvious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking at a border case - is a zero-sized array empty or not? Ignoring that specific question, the standard quote says that a general `std::array<T,N> arr`, on default construction, does not satisfy the post-condition `arr.empty()`. In fact, an `std::array<T, N>` is `empty()` only when `N==0`. And this definition is natural as well - `std::array<T,N>::size()` is a `constexpr` with value `N` and `empty()` should be synonymous with `size() == 0`.